# How to split a string on regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

How do you incorporate a regular expression into the Python `string.split` method? Here is some sample code:

```
ip = '192.168.0.1:8080'
tokens = ip.split('[.|:]')
print tokens
```

This for some reason generates `['192.168.0.1:8080']`. Can someone point out what I'm missing? I've tried escaping characters and using double quotes, but nothing seems to change anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `re.split` if you want to split a string according to  a regex pattern.

```
tokens = re.split(r'[.:]', ip)
```

Inside a character class `|` matches a literal `|` symbol and note that `[.:]` matches a dot **or** colon (*`|` won't do the orring here*).

So you need to remove `|` from the character class or otherwise it would do splitting according to the pipe character also.

or

Use `string.split` along with `list_comprehension`.

```
>>> ip = '192.168.0.1:8080'
>>> [j for i in ip.split(':') for j in i.split('.')]
['192', '168', '0', '1', '8080']
```

Comment: `re.split` is considerably more expensive than `string.split` IIRC. If you know your strings are going to be IP addresses with ports, it might be better to do `temp = ip.split(':')` and then `tokens = temp[1].split('.')` and then `tokens.append(ip[1])`