Convert a list of time string to unique string format
I have a list of time string with different formats as shown
time = ["1:5 am", "1:35 am", "8:1 am", "9:14 am", "14:23 pm", "20:2 pm"]

dict = {'time': time}      
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)

and wanted to replace strings in list as shown below.
["01:05 am", "01:35 am", "08:01 am", "09:14 am", "14:23 pm", "20:02 pm"]

Not sure how to write a regex that format the string in DataFrame.

Did you mean to write [..., "09:14 am" ,"14:23 pm", ...]? I.e. there seems to be a comma missing between those two strings. Also, it's ill-advised to call a dictionary dict. It overwrites the built-in type dict.

A possible solution, which is based on regex.
(df['time'].str.replace(r'^(\d):', r'0\1:', regex=True)
     .str.replace(r':(\d)\s', r':0\1 ', regex=True))

The main ideas are:

With r'^(\d):', one matches a single digit at the beginning of the string followed by a colon (e.g., 1: in 1:5 am).

With r'0\1:', one adds a 0 before the captured single digit and retains the colon.

With r':(\d)\s', one matches a single digit after a colon and before a space (e.g., :5 in 1:5 am).

With r':0\1 ', one adds a 0 before the captured single digit and retains the colon and space.


Output:
0    01:05 am
1    01:35 am
2    08:01 am
3    09:14 am
4    14:23 pm
5    20:02 pm
Name: time, dtype: object


You can use pd.to_datetime + Series.dt.strftime + Series.str.lower:
import pandas as pd

time = ["1:5 am", "1:35 am", "8:1 am", "9:14 am", "14:23 pm", "20:2 pm"]

data = {'time': time}      
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['time_corrected'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%H:%M %p')
                        .dt.strftime('%H:%M %p')
                        .str.lower()
                        )

Output:
       time time_corrected
0    1:5 am       01:05 am
1   1:35 am       01:35 am
2    8:1 am       08:01 am
3   9:14 am       09:14 am
4  14:23 pm       14:23 pm
5   20:2 pm       20:02 pm

If you just want a list, you can do:
time_corrected = (pd.to_datetime(time, format='%H:%M %p')
                  .strftime('%H:%M %p')
                  .str.lower()
                  .tolist()
                  )

Output:
['01:05 am', '01:35 am', '08:01 am', '09:14 am', '14:23 pm', '20:02 pm']

On the format codes (i.e. '%H:%M %p'), see here.

You can split each time like show in this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/33536592/724039), do the formatting, and glue it together again:
import pandas as pd

time = ["1:5 am", "1:35 am", "8:1 am", "9:14 am", "14:23 pm", "20:2 pm"]

dict = {'time': time}      
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)

my_list = []
for t in time:
   s = ""
   a = ":"
   for k in [j for i in t.split(':') for j in i.split(' ')]:
      m = ("00"+k)[-2:] if k.isnumeric() else k
      s = s + m + a
      a = " " 
   #print(s)
   my_list.append(s)

dict = {'time': my_list}   
print(dict)

P.S. I am not a python developer, so I think there is probably a way to write this in a smarter way...

Pandas-dataframe based solutions work well in this case, however since your original input was a list, I was just curious to see if its possible to solve it without using pandas,
and as it turns out, it is!
Here is a simple list based approach without using pandas,
we simply use strings' zfill method to fill missing leading zeros after splitting the time on ":",
time = ["1:5 am", "1:35 am", "8:1 am", "9:14 am", "14:23 pm", "20:2 pm"]

for i in range(len(time)):
    suffix = time[i][-3:]
    x = time[i][:-3].split(":")
    x = [j.zfill(2) for j in x]
    time[i] = ":".join(x)+suffix

time

['01:05 am', '01:35 am', '08:01 am', '09:14 am', '14:23 pm', '20:02 pm'] 

